Spring Boot create schemas like Swagger UI
due limitation of swagger ui to not be able to show endpoints with same URI mapping but using different params, I'm looking for alternatives.
With a great help of @Abhishek Kotalwar in this question I could create a custom endpoint in /actuator path for all of my existed rest endpoints.
The next problem I'm facing is to describe the dto objects, that are required in the rest requests.
I'm aware, that I could create an example of each Dto object that exists in my project, but it seems not to be the efficient way, due high risk of inconsistency and maintainance efforts.
I'm looking for an automate way to create it by server start.
So, is there any way to iterate over all of my entities and dtos maybe based on the package name like "dto" or "model" with an intention to show the structure of the dto or entity and also to add validation information like when an attribute is marked with @NotBlank or @NotNull or @Email or other annotations?
Thanks a lot in advance!
Problem Example:
PostMapping(value = "/api/users", params = "type=customer") 
public ResponseEntity<String> createUser(CustomerRequest req) {...} 

PostMapping(value = "/api/users", params = "type=owner") 
public ResponseEntity<String> createUser(OwnerRequest req) {...} 

According to the example, open api will only take the CustomRequest into their schema, OwnerRequest not (I guess first find alphabetically), because of the identical uri.
I tried to create handmade examples of dto and entity objects and add them to a custom endpoint.
I'm looking for an automate way to create it by server start.

You can define swagger-ui and open-api schemas by their dependency. By using their annotations on endpoint, you can make more accurate descriptions of your api.
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-rest-openapi-documentation

@chris576 if you have two identical endpoint values but different params, open-api schema takes only all parameters from one of the two identical endpoint, the other one will be ignored.
Added an example of my problem.
